# Keras model.fit() with tf.dataset fails while using tf.train works fine

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Summary: according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/Model#fit), Keras `model.fit()` should accept tf.dataset as input (I am using TF version 1.12.0). I can train my model if I manually do the training steps but using `model.fit()` on the same model, I get an error I cannot resolve.

Here is a sketch of what I did: my dataset, which is too big to fit in the memory, consists of many files each with different number of rows of (100 features, label). I'd like to use `tf.data` to build my data pipeline:

```py
def data_loader(filename):
    '''load a single data file with many rows'''
    features, labels = load_hdf5(filename)
    ...
    return features, labels

def make_dataset(filenames, batch_size):
    '''read files one by one, pick individual rows, batch them and repeat'''
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)
    dataset = dataset.map(      # Problem here! See edit for solution
        lambda filename: tuple(tf.py_func(data_loader, [filename], [float32, tf.float32])))
    dataset = dataset.flat_map(
        lambda features, labels: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels)))
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat()
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(1000)
    return dataset

_BATCH_SIZE = 128
training_set = make_dataset(training_files, batch_size=_BATCH_SIZE)
```

I'd like to try a very basic logistic regression model:

```py
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(100,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax')(inputs)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

If I train it *manually* everything works fine, e.g.:

```py
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.backend.categorical_crossentropy(labels, outputs))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(.05).minimize(loss)

iterator = training_set.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)
    for i in range(training_size // _BATCH_SIZE):
        x, y = sess.run(next_element)
        train_step.run(feed_dict={inputs: x, labels: y})
```

However, if I instead try to use `model.fit` like this:

```py
model.compile('adam', 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(training_set.make_one_shot_iterator(),
          steps_per_epoch=training_size // _BATCH_SIZE,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1)
```

I get an error message `ValueError: Cannot take the length of Shape with unknown rank.` inside the keras'es `_standardize_user_data` function.

I have tried quite a few things but could not resolve the issue. Any ideas?

**Edit:** based on @kvish's answer, the solution was to change the map from a lambda to a function that would specify the correct tensor dimensions, e.g.:

```py
def data_loader(filename):
    def loader_impl(filename):
        features, labels, _ = load_hdf5(filename)
        ...
        return features, labels

    features, labels = tf.py_func(loader_impl, [filename], [tf.float32, tf.float32])
    features.set_shape((None, 100))
    labels.set_shape((None, 1))
    return features, labels
```

and now, all needed to do is to call this function from `map`:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(data_loader)
```

Comment: Do you still get the error if you just pass `training_set` to the `fit` method?

Comment: Yes, it has the same issue.

Comment: @AlefSin since you are using tf.py_func, maybe it needs to know the shape when using Keras? Can you can set shape of the tensor you get from tf.py_func using set_shape(your_shape) method and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: @kvish wow! Wonderful. That did the trick, thanks a lot! If you submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @AlefSin sure! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably tf.py_func produces an unknown shape which Keras cannot infer. We can set the shape of the tensor returned by it using set_shape(your_shape) method and that would help Keras infer the shape of the result.